# Azure : ResourceNotFound from az cli but resource exist in Portal

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-cli2

Facing this "ResourceNotFound" issue (JPG-1), but I can see the logicapp resource in Azure portal(JPG-2)

```
(ResourceNotFound) The Resource 'Microsoft.Web/sites/us-analytics-dev-dsvm-auto-deletion-logicapp-eastus2' under resource group 'us-analytics-dev-dsvm-auto-deletion-eastus2' was not found. For more details please go to https://aka.ms/ARMResourceNotFoundFix
Code: ResourceNotFound
Message: The Resource 'Microsoft.Web/sites/us-analytics-dev-dsvm-auto-deletion-logicapp-eastus2' under resource group 'us-analytics-dev-dsvm-auto-deletion-eastus2' was not found. For more details please go to https://aka.ms/ARMResourceNotFoundFix
```

[image: JPG-1]

[image: JPG-2]

Note :

1. Already configured (us-analytics-dev) as default subscription in
   cli.
2. Logicapp resource created through Terraform (Code below : code-1)

[image]

**Code-1** :(edited)

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "dsvm_auto_deletion_resource_group" {
  name     = "us-analytics-dev-dsvm-auto-deletion-logicapp-eastus2"
  location = "East US 2"
}

resource "azurerm_logic_app_workflow" "dsvm_auto_deletion_logicapp" {
  name                = "us-analytics-dev-dsvm-auto-deletion-logicapp-eastus2"
  location            = "East US 2"
  resource_group_name = "us-analytics-dev-dsvm-auto-deletion-eastus2"
}
```

Comment: Please post code and errors as text, not screenshots unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: Added Terraform code and error as text @MarkoE

Comment: Does the name of the resource group have to match what you are showing when running `az account show` under the `name` key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note I noticed your azurerm_resource_group resource name is the same as your azurerm_logic_app_workflow resource name but I think it is just a typo :)

I tried the same command as you and it didn't work for me, it kept returning empty list, I think something is wrong with the az logicapp command.

After some research I found that there is a package in **preview** that can be used instead which is **logic workflow**.
Just past in the following command and install the package and it should work, so for your case it would be something like :

```
az logic workflow show -g us-analytics-dev-dsvm-auto-deletion-eastus2 --name us-analytics-dev-dsvm-auto-deletion-logicapp-eastus2
```