# ResourceNotFound When Running Azure CLI for StaticWebApp CORS

Tags: azure, cors, azure-cli, azure-static-web-app

I'm simply running the following command:

```
az webapp cors show --resource-group <rg> --name <name_of_the_app>
```

But I'm getting the following message:

```
(ResourceNotFound) The Resource 'Microsoft.Web/sites/<name_of_the_app>' under resource group '<rg>' was not found. For more details please go to https://aka.ms/ARMResourceNotFoundFix
Code: ResourceNotFound
Message: The Resource 'Microsoft.Web/sites/<name_of_the_app>' under resource group '<rg>' was not found. For more details please go to https://aka.ms/ARMResourceNotFoundFix
```

It really doesn't make sense, as both resource group and app_name exists in the portal.
And `az staticwebapp` command isn't the right choice, as it doesn't have an option for CORS.

There is [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74907266/azure-resourcenotfound-from-az-cli-but-resource-exist-in-portal) where someone experienced `ResourceNotFound`, and one of the commenters mentioned that something may be wrong with azure command.

EDIT

- Tried az login, az group list, checked typos
- Tried using different options such:
  `az webapp cors show --ids <resouce_id>`
- What's interesting is that error description says:
  `Microsoft.Web/sites/<name_of_the_app>`.
- My static web app json view shows: `"type": "Microsoft.Web/staticSites"`

Could this be a possible bug?

Answer (score 0):

So firstly, **web apps** and **static web apps** are treated as **two different resources** in Azure.

You're trying to use the `az webapp` command to update a different resource which is a static web app in this case which is why you get the error that there is so such resource of type webapp in your resource group and rightly so.

Also just because the `az staticwebapp` command doesn't have the option to set a cors policy doesn't mean that `az webapp` command qualifies as the "correct" command. Instead this just means that currently the `az staticwebapp` command doesn't support adding CORS policies using the cli.

If you are looking for a way to set CORS policies for a static webapp, you will need to set it in the `staticwebapp.config.json` as global headers. see : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/static-web-apps/configuration#global-headers

[image]

Comment: Thanks Rimaz, for your response. Yes, I have gone extra steps by re-logging in, running az group list, checking typos, and etc. What I'm going to do now is to rephrase my question a little bit to see if it gives additional context.